Azure devops search pull requests by source branch
In Azure devops, is there a way to filter pull requests by source branch. It's possible to filter by target branch, but source branch doesn't appear to be available as an option. How do I go about this?

Do you only care about Active PRs, or historical ones as well (including Completed and/or Abandoned).

Not too fussed about abandoned, but completed, yes. I was trying to deteremined the list of feature PRs that contributed to a release PR. I've done it manually now, but if it's possible to do programmatically, that would be useful.

You can do it using the Azure DevOps CLI.
Use the az repos pr list command to list pull requests filtered by source branch:
az repos pr list [--creator]
                 [--detect {false, true}]
                 [--include-links]
                 [--org]
                 [--project]
                 [--repository]
                 [--reviewer]
                 [--skip]
                 [--source-branch]
                 [--status {abandoned, active, all, completed}]
                 [--target-branch]
                 [--top]

Example:
ORGANIZATION="https://dev.azure.com/my-org"
PROJECT="my-project"
TOKEN="....."

REPOSITORY="my-repository"
SOURCE_BRANCH="my-source-branch"
PR_STATUS="completed"

printf "\nTrying to login into Azure DevOps\n"
echo "$TOKEN" | az devops login

az repos pr list \
  --organization $ORGANIZATION \
  --project $PROJECT \
  --repository $REPOSITORY \
  --source-branch $SOURCE_BRANCH \
  --status $PR_STATUS \
  --output json


Thanks @rui. I get "repos is misspelled or not recognised by the system". I suspect it might be an extension? I work for a bank and our PCs are very locked down and it's unlikely I'll be able to add this. Is there any other way to do this? Seems like something that should just be part of the filter in the interface.

@MarkRoworth is the Azure DevOps CLI installed? Check the first link in my answer. The alternative would be to use the Azure DevOps REST CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-5.0

I've got 2.58.0 installed and the help page states "The extension will automatically install the first time you run an az repos pr command", but this clearly isn't happening. Even if I just run az --version part of the response states: "Unable to check if your CLI is up-to-date. Check your internet connection." I think this isn't an option for me. Presumably blocked by a firewall or something like that.

Nothing I can do regarding corporate policies :(

You can install this extension Pull Request Manager Hub from the marketplace.

This extension supports filtering by project, team, repo, source branch, target branch, create by and reviewers.


I am afraid that there is no built-in option in Azure DevOps can filter the Pull request based on Source Branch.
Currently, Azure DevOps only supports setting Target Branch as filter in Pull Request UI page.
According to the previous comments, additional components cannot be installed due to limitations on your machine.
I suggest that you can use the PowerShell to run the Rest API: Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests to get the Pull request based on Source Branch.
Here is an example:
$token = "PAT"

$SourceBranchname = "refs/heads/sourcebranchname"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/git/repositories/{reponame}/pullrequests?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

foreach($Pullrequestinfo in $response.value)
{
   if($Pullrequestinfo.sourceRefName -eq $SourceBranchname)
   {
       $PullRequestID = $Pullrequestinfo.pullRequestId
       $PullRequestStatus = $Pullrequestinfo.status

       echo "PullReuqestID: $PullRequestID"
       echo "PullRequestStatus: $PullRequestStatus"
   }
}

Result:

In this case, you can run it directly using PowerShell after filling in the relevant parameters without installing additional components.

In Azure DevOps, in the branches view, there is a Pull Request column which will  show a PR number (with a link to it) if there is at least one Active PR or Draft for that source branch. Note this will not show Completed PR's, and if there are multiple PRs, I believe this will show the oldest PR in that column.
If you wish to see all Active PRs for a source branch, you can use the GET API in any browser where you are already logged in, for example if you want to find all PRs in a repository called MyRepo where the source branch is user/first.last/my-feature-1:
[url-prefix]/_apis/git/repositories/MyRepo/pullRequests?searchCriteria.sourceRefName=refs/heads/user/first.last/my-feature-1

# where [url-prefix] is the same prefix as your normal UI usage, e.g.:
[url-prefix]/_git/WTS/branches?_a=all

If you wish to see all existing and historical PRs for that source branch, (including Abandoned and Completed) then append &searchCriteria.status=all to the query:
[url-prefix]/_apis/git/repositories/MyRepo/pullRequests?searchCriteria.sourceRefName=refs/heads/user/first.last/my-feature-1&searchCriteria.status=all

All of the Pull Request API Options are described here. You can adjust the query filters as needed.
